# How to control the width of bar graph in anglar using apexcharts

Tags: angular, angular-material, apexcharts

I am using apexcharts for displaying a bar graph where a date range can be set. it works well but I observe that when the date range is less, the columns are too wide

[image]

The graph has 2 data only for 2 days in the given time range but the column width makes it look like it covers 3-5 days. Is there anyway to reduce  the width of the column?